# Ergodicity of irrational rotation map

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I want to check the ergodicity of irrational rotation map without using Fourier series. $T:\frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}} \to \frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}}$ which $ x \mapsto x+q$ , $\mod \ 1$  where $q \in \mathbb{Q}^c$.

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the Borel-$\sigma$- algebra and $\mu(B) = \mu(a+B)$ , $B \in \mathcal{B}$ where $a+B=\{a+b | b \in B \}$

I wanna check the ergodicity by using the fact that for every $A,B$ in the Borel sigma algebra we have :

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \mu(T^{-i}A \cap B)=\mu(A)\cdot\mu(B)$

or

$\forall B$ in the Borel sigma algebra where $\mu(B) > 0$ : $\mu(\bigcup T^{-i}B)=1$

Any help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ergodicity of irrational rotation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085810/ergodicity-of-irrational-rotation)

Comment: No I want to use the above theorem to prove this. I mean :
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \mu(T^{-i}A \cap B)=\mu(A)\cdot\mu(B)$

or

$\forall B$ in the Borel sigma algebra where $\mu(B) > 0$ : $\mu(\bigcup T^{-i}B)=1$

Comment: It's usually not possible or very difficult to prove a system is ergodic directly from the definition you want to use.  The proof in the linked answer is the most standard proof of this fact that doesn't use Fourier analysis